# How can I claim a refund from a failed ICO (Watertech)

Tags: tokens, gas-refund

My questions is about claiming a refund from a failed ICO. The ICO in question is WaterTech and the token is WATR

Answer (score 1):

I assume they organized an ICO and the minimum limit was not reached?
In any case, if the contract doesn't include any refund options (automatically or manually) then your only option is to contact the organizers.

Or if you mean that the ICO was an exit scam there's very little you can do. Of course you can always try to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2845135.0), they have already started refunds which can be viewed [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x44bbb437cef95d4f4236b9505d7df3c1cf38c0e3), reported from the 1st link.

Search that 2nd link for your address. If not, I would advise to contact them directly.